# CSS Iteration count and stop code not working

Tags: html, css, web

How can I make this loop once, and then it remain as written unless page is reloaded? I tried many things I read. Could you please amend the code so I can see where you're inserting it?

Simply what i'm trying is to make it appear once, then remain until the page is reloaded or something.

Thank you!

I sincerely appreciate it.

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');

body {
  text-align:center;
  background:none;
  color:white;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:32px;
  padding-top:5vh;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:first-of-type {    /* For increasing performance 
                       ID/Class should've been used. 
                       For a small demo 
                       it's okaish for now */
  animation: showup 10s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:last-of-type {
  width:0px;
  animation: reveal 10s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:last-of-type span {
  margin-left:-355px;
  animation: slidein 10s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes showup {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    20% {opacity:1;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% { margin-left:-800px; }
    20% { margin-left:-800px; }
    35% { margin-left:0px; }
    100% { margin-left:0px; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
}

@keyframes reveal {
    0% {opacity:0;width:0px;}
    20% {opacity:1;width:0px;}
    30% {width:355px;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:1;width:355px; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
}
      
@keyframes grow {
  0% { font-size: 0; }
  100% { font-size: 40px; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards; }
  
}
p {
  font-size:12px;
  color:white;
  margin-top:200px;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
  <div>Escape</div> 
<div> 
  <span>into amazing experiences</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `showup` keyframe ends in 0 `opacity`.

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');

body {
  text-align:center;
  background:none;
  color:red;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:32px;
  padding-top:5vh;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:first-of-type {    /* For increasing performance 
                       ID/Class should've been used. 
                       For a small demo 
                       it's okaish for now */
  animation: showup 10s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:last-of-type {
  width:0px;
  animation: reveal 10s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:last-of-type span {
  margin-left:-355px;
  animation: slidein 10s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes showup {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    20% {opacity:1;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:1; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% { margin-left:-800px; }
    20% { margin-left:-800px; }
    35% { margin-left:0px; }
    100% { margin-left:0px; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
}

@keyframes reveal {
    0% {opacity:0;width:0px;}
    20% {opacity:1;width:0px;}
    30% {width:355px;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:1;width:355px; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
}
      
@keyframes grow {
  0% { font-size: 0; }
  100% { font-size: 40px; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards; }
  
}
p {
  font-size:12px;
  color:white;
  margin-top:200px;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
  <div>Escape</div> 
<div> 
  <span>into amazing experiences</span>
</div>
```